# PHP print every second hour?

Tags: php, date, charts, google-visualization

Is there a easier/better way to get every second hour than this

```
if(date("H")=='00'){$chart_updates = '|02|04|06|08|10|12|14|16|18|20|22|00';}
if(date("H")=='01'){$chart_updates = '|03|05|07|09|11|13|15|17|19|19|23|01';}
if(date("H")=='02'){$chart_updates = '|04|06|08|10|12|14|16|18|20|21|00|02';}
if(date("H")=='03'){$chart_updates = '|05|07|09|11|13|15|17|19|21|23|01|03';}
if(date("H")=='04'){$chart_updates = '|06|08|10|12|14|16|18|20|22|00|02|04';}
if(date("H")=='05'){$chart_updates = '|07|09|11|13|15|17|19|21|23|01|03|05';}
if(date("H")=='06'){$chart_updates = '|08|10|12|14|16|18|20|22|00|02|04|06';}
if(date("H")=='07'){$chart_updates = '|09|11|13|15|17|19|21|23|01|03|05|07';}
if(date("H")=='08'){$chart_updates = '|10|12|14|16|18|20|22|00|02|04|06|08';}
if(date("H")=='09'){$chart_updates = '|11|13|15|17|19|21|23|01|03|05|07|09';}
if(date("H")=='10'){$chart_updates = '|12|14|16|18|20|22|00|02|04|06|08|10';}
if(date("H")=='11'){$chart_updates = '|13|15|17|19|21|23|01|03|05|07|09|11';}
if(date("H")=='12'){$chart_updates = '|14|16|18|20|22|00|02|04|06|08|10|12';}
if(date("H")=='13'){$chart_updates = '|15|07|19|21|23|01|03|05|07|09|11|13';}
if(date("H")=='14'){$chart_updates = '|16|08|20|22|00|02|04|06|08|10|12|14';}
if(date("H")=='15'){$chart_updates = '|17|09|21|23|01|03|05|07|09|11|13|15';}
if(date("H")=='16'){$chart_updates = '|18|20|22|00|02|04|06|08|10|12|16|16';}
if(date("H")=='17'){$chart_updates = '|19|21|23|01|03|05|07|09|11|13|15|17';}
if(date("H")=='18'){$chart_updates = '|20|22|00|02|04|06|08|10|12|14|16|18';}
if(date("H")=='19'){$chart_updates = '|21|23|01|03|05|07|09|11|13|15|17|19';}
if(date("H")=='20'){$chart_updates = '|22|00|02|04|06|08|10|12|14|16|18|20';}
if(date("H")=='21'){$chart_updates = '|23|01|03|05|07|09|11|13|15|17|19|21';}
if(date("H")=='22'){$chart_updates = '|00|02|04|06|08|10|12|14|16|18|20|22';}
if(date("H")=='23'){$chart_updates = '|01|03|05|07|09|11|13|15|17|19|21|23';}
```

I need this for google charts and wanted to check if this way is stupid.

Answer (score 4):

1) take the current hour

2) mod2 (there are only two different sets of numbers, odd and even)

3) build array of hours

4) sort array by value

5) split array where the original hour was, and recombine.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create an array with keys:

```
$theHour['00'] = '|02|04|06|08|10|12|14|16|18|20|22|00';
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$chart_updates = $theHour[date("H")];
```

There is also probably a better way to generate this too, but since you already typed it out, its there.. It would just suck if you want to make a change.

Answer (score 1):

```
$h = date("H");
$line = '';
for($i=0; $i<=24; $i++)
{
    if($i % 2 == $h % 2)
        $line .= '|' . ($i < 10 ? '0'.$i : $i);
}
```

Comment: it is important to print 00 instead 24 but i think i can handle that alone,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nice code :)

There's actually much easier way to do this in php:

```
$chars = array();
$start = date("H")+2;
for( $i = 0; $i < 12; $i++){
    $chars[] = str_pad( ($start+2*$i)%24, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$chart_updates = '|' . implode( '|', $chars);
```

Comment: but then i will get |24|26|28|30|32|34|36|38|40|42|44|46 :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    function helper_add($h,$plus=0){
        if($h+$plus > 23){
            return $h+$plus-24;
        }
        return $h+$plus;
    }
    function helper_10($in){
        return $in < 10 ? '0'.$in : $in;
    }
    function getchartupdates(){
        $now = date('G');
        for($i=($now%2==0?0:1); $i<=24 ;$i+=2)
            $res[] = helper_10(helper_add($now,$i));
        return '|'.implode('|',$res);
    }
```

used [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php4/) to test it !